# NumPy: matrix by vector multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I've got 1 matrix named `A1` (18,11) and 3 vectors named `norms`, `offsets` and `priorita` (18,1).

When I try to do this operation:

```
A1 =  (A1 + offsets) / norms * priorita
```

I get the following error:

```
A1 =  (A1 + offsets) / norms * priorita
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 330, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I cannot understand it because the matrices look aligned to me. Can you please help me understand this error?

Comment: if `norms`, `offsets`, `priorita` have `ndim=2`, it should work if you use `offsets.ravel()`, `norms.ravel()`, `priorita.ravel()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a `matrix`, no matter it is a `matrix` and an `array` or two `matrixt`s. `*` is always seen as matrix multiplication, hence the `not aligned` error because it is simply not conducting a cell wise operation. You see the traceback goes to  `__mul__()` in `defmatrix.pyc`

To do the vector-wise operation you intended, use `np.multiply((A1 + offsets) / norms , priorita)`, it is the same thing as `np.matrix(np.array((A1 + offsets) / norms )* np.array(priorita))`, but slightly faster, and reads better I think.

Comment: `np.multiply((A1 + offsets) / norms , priorita)` is the way to go. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `.shape` of `(A1 + offsets) / norms` is `(18, 11)`. You cannot multiply a `(18, 11)` matrix by a `(18, 1)` vector (the second/column dimension of the first matrix has to equal the dimension of the vector). I'm not sure what your actual goal here is, but you probably want to transpose the matrix, assuming your goal is standard matrix-vector multiplication:

```
A1 =  ((A1 + offsets) / norms).T * priorita
```